# Self sizing tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

First of all this is not a question about how to automatically size the cells inside the tableview, moreover how to automatically resize the entire tableview.

So I have a scrollview which has a tableview and 2 other views as its subviews. The tableview's cells already automatically resize itself, again this question is not about the individual cells. However, the tableview does not resize at all.

What I have done:
1) Set up the tableview to have a top, bottom, leading and trailing constraint
2) Set the cells up to have auto layout enabled
3) * I do not know the cell size at build time
4) I have disabled scrolling mode on tableview

So long story short, how can I go along to get the tableview to resize itself?

**Edit**

The cells contain a label which can have various lines of text, so therefore the cells, which use auto layout, should then determine the height of the table view.

The following images show how the view is set up:

[image: Quinchol]
[image: Quinchol 2]

As you can see the tableview is only a small part of the view and since the scrollview from the tableview is deactivated there should, and aren't, any scrolling problems.

**EDIT 2**

This is actually how it should end however, i am calculating this on my own and everytime I want to make a small change to the cells the whole code, which calculates the height of the cell, needs to be rewritten and it is quite difficult for me to get the height just right.

**Edit 3**

Until now I had a height constraint on the tableview which I calculated manually, however removing this constraint and trying to let auto layout handle the tableview height size creates the following error:

> Scroll View
>   Need constraint for: Y position or height

I can conclude therefore that the tableview does not know how to automatically calculate the height based on its cells with autolayout.

Comment: `UITableView` inside `UIScrollView` is an antipattern because it breaks the reusing of cells but if you really want to do that, add a height constraint and set it to `tableView.contentSize.height` programatically and after every data update. The height cannot be determined from cells.

Comment: Dynamically resizing a table view based on the *cell* heights is unusual... Maybe if you described better what your end goal is? You say *"tableview and 2 other views"* ... Might you be better off  using the 'other views' as Header and Footer views on the table? Then you wouldn't need the additional scroll view at all.

Comment: Or... maybe you shouldn't be using a Table View at all. I'm guessing you're not expecting a 500+ row table? There are other ways to show repeating variable-height views which may be a much better (easier) route than using table view cells.

Comment: So... is there some reason you don't want to use just a table view?

Comment: Well, I could probably do it without a table view but it would be quite difficult and a pain to do it. If it is possible to do it with a table view I would like to it so otherwise I will do it without

Comment: Looking at the images you've added, it looks like a pretty straight-forward table view. No need to resize the table based on the contents so you can move it in a scroll view... just let a normal UITableView handle it all.

Comment: Well it isn't that simple. There are many different views with the same layout however, the number of cells and the amount of text in each cell vary a lot.

Comment: But Table Views (and Collection Views) are pretty much designed for what you are doing. You can design as many different types of cells as you want, to handle all your different types of information to display... they can all be auto-sizing... and the Table/Collection view handles all of the scrolling for you. Unless there are some key details you haven't mentioned, it *really, really, really* sounds like you are over-complicating things.

Comment: So what you are basically saying is that I should create one tableview where the first cell should be the image gallary and the last one the description? I'm known to overcomplicate things so its quite possible.

Comment: Sure - 1st row your "gallery" and last row the description. Or, if it's always `gallery-row-row-row-etc-description`, you could use the table header view for the gallery and footer view for the description. If it's sometimes `image-row-row-image-image-row-row-description-image` then you're probably better off with multiple cell types.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I finally decided to not use a tableview at all, moreover I just created the cells myself with a loop creating each cell and placing them inside a blank uiview which then autoresizes using autolayout

Comment: you have to set tableView height  equal to tabView content size. after all data sets up in tableView.

Answer (score 14):

You don't need to create a height constraint or set frame whatsoever. Create a subclass of UITableView and recalculate its `intrinsicContentSize` every time its `contentSize` changes aka new data added or removed. Here is all you needed:

```
class SelfSizingTableView: UITableView {
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let height = min(.infinity, contentSize.height)
        return CGSize(width: contentSize.width, height: height)
    }
}
```

Comment: why setting the `height = min(.infinity, contentSize.height)`?  When `contentSize.height` is always less than or equal to `.infinity`?  Or is it?

Comment: @eja08 Nice catch. `.infinity` can be replaced with a maxHeight variable so that the tbv will stop growing after a certain point. I just didn't include it here.

Answer (score -2):

You can change your `UITableView's` frame by using `tableview.frame = CGRect(x: <some_x>, y: <some_y>, width: <some_width>, height: <some_height>)`

If your `UITableViewCells` use auto layout then they should resize when the `UITableView's` frame changes.

Comment: The idea is that the cells determine the tableviews height not the other way around.

Comment: Can you provide an example using an image or another application that uses this technique? Why would you want your cells to size your table view? This doesn't really conform to any normal design patters and I would reconsider this approach based on my understanding of your question.